# Do other methods exist than the method of image charges for computing equipotential field at surface around charged objects?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, computational-physics, method-of-images

I am trying to find another method for robotics based on "attractive-repulsive" forces s.t. first object forms the target to reach and the second one (and others) forms the obstacle to avoid. The method of image charges is nice but leads to quite some computational issues ..... as you can imagine due to the infinite many image charges that occur in the computation.

I formulated a totally different method based on a grand canonical potential field based on simply distance measures between targets and obstacles ensuring that the potential field is always constant at the objects' real or safety zone surfaces (force fields perpendicular to surfaces do go to zero but the tangential parts caused by attractive charges ensure tangential object avoidance near obstacle surfaces). Similarly, I formulate vector potential fields for aligning frame fields (one for each field) such that e.g. grasping of objects by fingers can be achieved. In addition, as space is orientated I can take advantage of negative distance measures (metrics) to ensure approach from the proper direction.

Summarising, does anybody know about such alternative methods from literature?

Comment: This site, [Computational Physics - Electric field lines](https://compphys.go.ro/electric-field-lines/) may be of some use?  There are many others!

Comment: ThX Farcher! Problem is that in robotics we do not have any idea about the charge (re)distribution within the objects.  So what I know is the position of each objects and its geometry and topology and formulated a grand canonical potential field that ensures attraction with the target and avoidance of the obstacles (robot is aware of the target so to move even in the opposite direction of the repulsive forces overshadowing the attractive one perhaps taking advantage of inter-relations between the obstacles he or she has to pass by).

Comment: Perhaps another question to be addressed by physicists is why there is a differences between charge and mass needed between gravitational, electro-magnetic and other forces - I do not not see it yet?